# How do I determine which Locator is selected in a LocatorPane with multiple Locators?

Tags: dynamic, locator

This is a cross-post of http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1186782

I am working on something where I need to know which locator out of many is currently being changed.

Here is some working code that uses the second argument to Dynamic to identify which locator is active for a limited set of Locators. I'd like to extend this to many Locators. In this code, the Locators are hard-coded. I'd like to extend this programmatically so I can slot in the Locators and the Manipulator controls. I've tried various combinations of Hold* without really knowing what I am doing.

Does anyone know how I can achieve my goal of finding which is the active locator?

See some additional comments below the working code about an attempt to do this with LocatorPane.

```
DynamicModule[
 {active = 0, p},
 Manipulate[
  Column[
   {active,
     Deploy@Graphics[
      {
       {
        Locator@
         Dynamic[p[1, 1, 
           1], {((p[1, 1, 1] = {-1, Last[#]}; 
              active = {1, 1, 1}) &), ((active = 0) &)}],
        Locator@
         Dynamic[p[1, 1, 
           2], {((p[1, 1, 2] = #; 
              active = {1, 1, 2}) &), ((active = 0) &)}],
        Locator@
         Dynamic[p[1, 1, 
           3], {((p[1, 1, 3] = {1, Last[#]}; 
              active = {1, 1, 3}) &), (active = 0) &}]
        },
       Line[{p[1, 1, 1], p[1, 1, 2], p[1, 1, 3]}] 
       },
      PlotRange -> 2
      ]
    }
   ],
  {{p[1, 1, 1], {-1, -1}}, ControlType -> None},
  {{p[1, 1, 2], {0, 0}}, ControlType -> None},
  {{p[1, 1, 3], {1, 1}}, ControlType -> None}
  ]
 ]
```

Trying to do the same thing with a LocatorPane and Nearest. It is not clear to me that the 2 argument form of Dynamic is working here:

```
DynamicModule[{active = False, pt1 = {1, 1}/2, pt2 = {-1, 1}/2, 
  pt3 = {1, -1}/2},
 Row[
  {active,
   LocatorPane[
    {
     Dynamic[
      pt1, {((active = Nearest[pt1, #, 1][[1]]); 
         pt1 = {0, 1} #) &, ((active = 0) &)}],
     Dynamic[
      pt2, {((active = Nearest[pt2, #, 1][[1]]); 
         pt2 = #) &, ((active = 0) &)}]
     },
    Graphics[{Yellow, Disk[{0, 0}, 2]},
     PlotRange -> 2
     ]
    ]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: I'd suggest using an `Association` back-end to your `Locator` GUI if you need to do big stuff with it. That's what I did for [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154868/38205). Then you can use some merger of user6014 and Mathe172's ideas.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is nice. Yours and @Mathe172's method are a nice set of bookends for this problem. I just noticed, b3m2a1's comment of using Associations which make sense as well.  Many thanks all, I consider this one solved.

Comment: This issue is addressed in my answer here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22134/how-to-dynamically-update-locator-constraints/22162#22162 (almost the same as Mathe172's)

Comment: It seems as though someone from Wolfram has posted a better solution than the ones below in the Wolfram Community. Neat!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [`MousePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MousePosition.html) set to the `"Graphics"` of the [`LocatorPane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html) with [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html).

```
pts = {{1, 1}/2, {-1, 1}/2, {1, -1}/2};
selectedLocator = None;
LocatorPane[
 Dynamic[pts,
  {
   (selectedLocator = 
      FirstPosition[pts, First@Nearest[pts, MousePosition[{"Graphics", LocatorPane}]]]) &,
   Automatic,
   None
   }],
 Graphics[{Yellow, Disk[{0, 0}, 2]}, PlotRange -> 2],
 LocatorAutoCreate -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Dynamic[selectedLocator]
```

When the `LocatorPane` beings to update locator the `MousePosition` in the pane's `"Graphics"` coordinates will be used to calculate the index of the nearest locator in `pts` and store this position in `selectedLocator`. This calculation only occurs at the start of updating a locator which reduces the load on the system.

With `LocatorAutoCreate` set to `True` additional locators can be added by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicking on the `LocatorPane`.

`selectedLocator` can be set to `None` in the third item of the second parameter of `Dynamic` if needed; `(selectedLocator = None)&`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great. Nice to see several alternatives. Thanks.

Comment: @CraigCarter Note the this solution works without the limitations listed in Mathe172 update.

Comment: And thank you @Edmund  for the nice explanatory text.

Answer (score 6):

Does this work for you?

```
DynamicModule[
 {pts = Array[pt, 5], active},
 Column@{
   Dynamic@active,
   Dynamic@pts,
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[
     pts,
     {
      (active = First@FirstPosition[pts - #, _?(# != {0, 0} &)]; pts = #)&,
      (active = None) &
     }
    ],
    Graphics[{Yellow, Disk[{0, 0}, 2]}, PlotRange -> 2]
    ]
   }
 ]
```

This simply finds the currently updating point by checking which value has changed.

#### Update

Seeing @user6014's solution, I thought I'd point out some issues I see with both apporaches:

- My approach fails if you don't actually change the position of the locator (you can do this by clicking once to get the locator directly under your cursor and then clicking again without moving the mouse)
- @user6014's approach fails if you manage to put two locators on top of each other (or at least it might not find the correct locator)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is nice. Yours and @Mathe172's method are a nice set of bookends for this problem. I just noticed, b3m2a1's comment of using Associations which make sense as well. Many thanks all, I consider this one solved

Comment: You should change your `active` setting call to be in the first function of the 3 function version `Dynamic` and clear `active` in the final function. It'll be cleaner that way.

Comment: Good point, updated. (Although I had have to use the two function version, otherwise you'll run into the problem I mentioned at the bottom of the answer)

Answer (score 5):

Does this work for you?

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{-1, 1}/2, {1, 1}/2}, a = False, 
  pointNames = Table["Point " <> ToString@i, {i, 10}]},
 EventHandler[
  {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], Framed@Graphics[{}], 
    LocatorAutoCreate -> True], Dynamic[a]}
  ,
  {"MouseUp" :> {a = "Null"}, 
   "MouseDragged" :> {a = 
      pointNames[[Position[pts, 
          Nearest[pts, MousePosition["Graphics"]][[1]]][[1, 1]]]]}}
  , PassEventsDown -> True]
 ]
```

This simply finds the point closest to your current mouse position when pressed down.

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click to create new locators.

Comment: Yes. This works like a charm.  Both yours and that of @Mathe172 can be used for my purposes. I like this approach with the EventHandler.  Many thanks.  Many thanks, I consider this one solved.